# Unexplained overflow x on page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I am working on a website and one of the pages has a weird overflow to the right of the page. I honestly cannot work out what is causing it after inspecting all of the elements. Would anyone mind taking a look to see if you can see what's causing this as I am stuck. Very grateful for any help! The url is: https://diabetesand.me/recipes/quick-and-easy-tacos

Comment: I have found out the culprit. It is a hidden search overlay with the class names 'search search-home show-popup' I am really not sure why this is being set at that width as the exact same markup/css on other pages is not causing this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem:

```
<img src="//ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=diabetesandme-21&amp;l=ur2&amp;o=2" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important; position: absolute!important;">
```

The quick solution is:

```
<img src="//ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=diabetesandme-21&amp;l=ur2&amp;o=2" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important; position: absolute!important; width: 1px;">
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan, I completely missed that and would have probably never found it.